# Which kind of regularity of a 2-dimensional manifold do we need to assume such that there is a surface measure and outer normal field on it?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, surfaces, manifolds-with-boundary

Let $M\subseteq\mathbb R^3$. I've got a very basic question, but since I'm not very familiar with differential geometry, I'm really lost by all the concepts for the moment.

I'd like to know which regularity assumptions we need to impose in order for $M$ being a $2$-dimensional manifold satisfying:

1. There is a well-defined surface measure on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $M$;
2. There is a unique outer normal field on $M$.

Maybe 2. needs to be phrased differently. For example, $M$ being a nondegenerate triangle should be allowed, but I guess then there is a problem with the normal field at the border. On the other hand, if we take only the interior of the triangle, this issue should disappear, shouldn't it?

I'd really appreciate any advice. I don't want to dive deep into this topic. 1. and 2. are just high-level assumptions I need to impose and I'm curious what exactly we would need to assume in order to guarantee them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is sufficient for $M$ to be an oriented embedded $C^1$-submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^3$ (possibly with boundary or even corners).  Being $C^1$ gives a well-defined tangent plane at each point, and then with an orientation you get a well-defined outer unit normal vector to the tangent plane at each point.  To get a surface measure, you just integrate the surface area $2$-form, which is just the $2$-form given by taking determinants with the normal vector.  Note that there isn't really any issue with the boundary here--the tangent plane is still perfectly well-defined at the boundary, even if half of the tangent plane is pointing "outside" the boundary.

Comment: (a) Is the construction of the surface measure analogously to the construction where $M$ is the boundary of a compact set with smooth boundary? (b) Shouldn't there be a problem at the edge of a triangle? Intuitively, it's not clear to me on which side the normal vector would be. And shouldn't there be infinitely many normal vectors at an edge point?

Comment: Yes, you won't have a continuous normal field if the submanifold is only piecewise-linear as opposed to $C^1$. But a single oriented triangular (or polygonal) face will be OK.

Comment: @0xbadf00d: (a) I'm not familiar with the construction you're referring to. (b) Well, how do you define "normal vector"?  I'm just defining it as a vector which is perpendicular to the tangent plane (which is unique if you specify unit norm and an orientation), and for that there's no problem at the edge of a triangle.  Of course you could try to make a more "geometric" definition of a normal vector for which maybe it wouldn't be unique at the edge of a triangle.

Comment: I think you're right. How do I need to understand the term *embedded* here? You just mean it is a submanifold of $\mathbb R^3$, right? I've got some problems to follow, since the $C^1$ requirement doesn't seem to fit for a triangle or a union of triangles. Something like "piecewise smooth" seems more natural to me, but I might be totally wrong. Do you have a reference for the claims maid in your answer?

Comment: @0xbadf00d: Being an embedded $C^1$ manifold (without boundary) means that each point of $M$ has a neighborhood in $\mathbb{R}^3$ which can be given $C^1$ local coordinates such that $M$ is a plane in those coordinates.  Allowing boundary means that $M$ can also be a closed half-plane instead of a plane, and allowing corners means that $M$ can also be a closed quarter-plane.  So a triangle works as an embedded $C^1$ manifold with corners: along edges it looks like a half-plane (up to local $C^1$ diffeomorphism), and at vertices it looks like a quarter-plane.

Comment: But a union of triangles glued together along their edges (like a polyhedron) does _not_ work, since when two edges are glued together at an angle, the result does not look locally like a plane, half-plane, or quarter plane (instead it looks like two half-planes joined at an angle).

Comment: I guess that's what I've got in mind in the first place: Consider the Polyhedron. Couldn't we just remove the edges of the glueing seams?

Comment: Sure, if you remove the edges of a polyhedron, all you have is a disjoint union of open polygons which is a perfectly nice (if disconnected) embedded submanifold.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I've got a related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3488093/47771. Maybe you can take a look.

Comment: Does $M$ itself even need to be a manifold? It seems like it's sufficient that $M$ is a union of sufficiently regular manifolds. Or would it then be already a manifold (but of less regular type)?

Comment: If $M$ is a union of manifolds that are open in $M$, then $M$ is also a manifold.  If they're not open in $M$ then you can't expect to have a unique tangent plane at a point where two different manifolds both accumulate.